# Partition list by delimiter

Tags: c#, linq, split

Is there an elegant way (with LINQ, for example) to partition a list into a list of sublists by delimiter? Partioning `{ 1, 2, delim, delim, 3, delim, 4, 5 }` by `delim` might produce `{ { 1, 2 }, { 3 }, { 4, 5 } }`....

Comment: @BalinKingOfMoria To make your example clearer, create a sublist with multiple elements and one without elements: { 1, 2, delim, delim, 3, delim, 4, 5 }

Comment: Thanks to everyone for all the fast answers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Directly in Linq, I think it will be hard, but you can create a custom operator. Maybe something like this :

```
List<String> test = new List<String>() { "1", "8", ";", "2", "7", "42", ";", "3" };
var restul = test.StrangePartition(";");
```

with :

```
public static class Helper
{
    public static IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> StrangePartition<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source, T partitionKey)
    {
        List<List<T>> partitions = new List<List<T>>();
        List<T> partition = new List<T>();
        foreach (T item in source)
        {

            if (item.Equals(partitionKey))
            {
                partitions.Add(partition);
                partition = new List<T>();
            }
            else
            {
                partition.Add(item);
            }
        }
        partitions.Add(partition);
        return partitions;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't think there is an easy and elegant way of doing so with default LINQ methods. But you can create your own extension method:

```
public static class MyExtensions
{
    public static IEnumerable<IEnumerable<TElement>> SplitBy<TElement>(
        this IEnumerable<TElement> source,
        TElement split,
        bool skipEmptyGroups = true)
        where TElement : IEquatable<TElement>
    {
        var group = new List<TElement>();

        foreach (var item in source)
        {
            if (split.Equals(item))
            {
                if (group.Count > 0 || !skipEmptyGroups)
                {
                    yield return group;
                    group = new List<TElement>();
                }
            }
            else
            {
                group.Add(item);
            }
        }

        if (group.Count > 0 || !skipEmptyGroups)
            yield return group;
    }
}
```

Usage is really simple:

```
var source = new List<int> { 1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 3, 5, 3, 6, 7, 8 };

var result = source.SplitBy(3);
```

If you want to return empty groups you can pass additional `bool` parameter:

```
var resultWithEmptyGroups = source.SplitBy(3, false);
```

Comment: Rather than restricting it to `IEqualtable<TElement>`, I'd just use the default equality comparer. Keep it more flexible.

Comment: You could do that, but than it might return weird results based on default, reference based equality.

Comment: Honestly, that should be no surprise to anyone. If the user wants a different way to compare the items, they should be given a choice by passing in their own comparer. If none is provided, fall back to the default. This method is restricted to a class of items when it doesn't have to.

Answer (score 0):

No, there isn't anything similar, but it's quite easy to implement them:

```
public static class LinqEx
{
    public static IEnumerable<List<TSource>> Split<TSource>(this IEnumerable<TSource> enu, TSource delimiter, IEqualityComparer<TSource> comparer = null)
    {
        // list == null handles the case where enu is empty
        List<TSource> list = null;

        if (comparer == null)
        {
            // Note how the equality comparer is "selected".
            // This is how LINQ methods do it
            // (see Enumerable.SequenceEqual<TSource>)
            comparer = EqualityComparer<TSource>.Default;
        }

        foreach (TSource el in enu)
        {
            if (comparer.Equals(el, delimiter))
            {
                if (list == null)
                {
                    list = new List<TSource>();
                }

                yield return list;

                // Note that we have to recreate the list every time! 
                // We can't simply do a list.Clear()
                list = new List<TSource>();
                continue;
            }

            if (list == null)
            {
                list = new List<TSource>();
            }

            list.Add(el);
        }

        if (list != null)
        {
            yield return list;
        }
    }

    public static IEnumerable<List<TSource>> SplitRemoveEmpty<TSource>(this IEnumerable<TSource> enu, TSource delimiter, IEqualityComparer<TSource> comparer = null)
    {
        var list = new List<TSource>();

        if (comparer == null)
        {
            // Note how the equality comparer is "selected".
            // This is how LINQ methods do it
            // (see Enumerable.SequenceEqual<TSource>)
            comparer = EqualityComparer<TSource>.Default;
        }

        foreach (TSource el in enu)
        {
            if (comparer.Equals(el, delimiter))
            {
                if (list.Count != 0)
                {
                    yield return list;

                    // Note that we have to recreate the list every time! 
                    // We can't simply do a list.Clear()
                    list = new List<TSource>();
                }

                continue;
            }

            list.Add(el);
        }

        if (list.Count != 0)
        {
            yield return list;
        }
    }
}
```

There are two variants: the first one (`Split`) will return even the empty groups, the second one will strip empty groups.

For example:

```
{ delim, 1, 2, delim, delim, 3, delim, 4, 5, delim }
```

With `Split` you will receive

```
{ { }, {1, 2}, { }, {3}, {4, 5}, { } }
```

While with `SplitRemoveEmpty`

```
{ {1, 2}, {3}, {4, 5} }
```

Use them like:

```
var res = new[] { 1, 2, 0, 0, 3, 4, 0, 5 }.SplitRemoveEmpty(0);

foreach (List<int> group in res)
{
    // Do something
}
```

Remember that these split methods are based on the correctness of the `Equals` method! But there is an optional last parameter where you can give an `IEqualityComparer<TSource>` that the methods will use instead of the default one.

Answer (score 0):

Although others mentioned it would be easier with an imperative approach, it is of course do-able in LINQ. The `Aggregate` operator has a lot of uses, but usually a poor readability.

```
var testCase = new List<String> { "1", "8", ";", "2", "7", "42", ";", "3" };
var result = testCase.Aggregate(new List<List<String>>() { new List<String>() }, (l, s) => {
    if (s == ";") {
        l.Add(new List<String>());
    } else {
        l[l.Count - 1].Add(s);
    }
    return l;
}).ToList();
```

It will produce the desired output, but its not only hard to comprehend, but it also produces side-effects within the query (not as bad as producing side-effects outside the query, but still ill-advised).

You can put it into your own extension method if you wishes so:

```
public static IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> PartitionBy(this IEnumerable<T> source, T delimiter) {
    return source.Aggregate(new List<List<T>>() { new List<T>() }, (l, elem) =>
        if(elem.Equals(delimiter)) {
            l.Add(new List<T>());
        } else {
            l[l.Count - 1].Add(elem);
        }
        return l;
    });
}
```

Again, consider this answer only for the completeness of a LINQ answer.